In a python stubs file, how to have a type without importing an external package?
Suppose I want to annotate pyarrow's pq.ParquetFile which takes a filesystem parameter. A valid input to that parameter is pyarrow's own FileSystem implementation. That is easy enough to just have filesystem: FileSystem | None but what I really want is filesystem: FileSystem | fsspec.AbstractFileSystem | None but the stubs shouldn't impose a dependency and since it's a pyi file it can't have try import (I don't think). While this is specifically what I'm actually trying to do I'm hoping it's a general solution not specific to pyarrow or fsspec.
Is there a way to do this?
I found this but it's a few years old so hoping there's a way to do it now.

I don't understand your problem: "stubs shouldn't impose a dependency". Is it an optional dependency that may or may not be present? Basically having .pyi file import a non-existent module isn't that bad: in the worst case this union will resolve to Any. It won't break anything. If you need to enforce this, you can declare the relevant package as an extra dependency (e.g. pip install 'your_package[types]') - this will only be necessary during type checking and just shouldn't be installed in production.

Even better, you can declare a Protocol listing the necessary members - this will support any class implementing the desired interface and won't impose any dependency on any specific implementation provided by some package. However, fsspec already provides such an interface, so requiring it as a dependency is also fine.
